# std::common_type with references to type_info

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm perplexed: upon upgrading to GCC 6 (RC1) some template code using `std::common_type` that worked before failed. I tried on clang, and that also fails...so I must be doing something wrong!

The code amounts to:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

// common_type of two const type_info& is ok (compiles ok)
common_type<const type_info&, const type_info&>::type func1();

// common_type of three type_info& is bad...(fails to compile)
common_type<const type_info&, const type_info&, const type_info&>::type func2();

// common_type of two const int& is ok
common_type<const int&, const int&>::type func3();

// common_type of three const int& is ok too!
common_type<const int&, const int&, const int&>::type func4();
```

The second `common_type` with three parameters of type `std::type_info const &` fails to compile. clang cryptically suggests I use a two-argument `std::common_type`, but this is in a template expansion where I can't control the inputs!

This seems very odd: why would the `const type_info&` case with 3 fail but not any of the other seemingly-equivalent type fail?

See here: https://godbolt.org/g/Ob4y0x

Comment: `common_type` now decays, and that result in "fun" things.

Comment: Some twitter references point me to the fact that `std::common_type` returns the `std::decay` of the Ts ... which is super annoying for my use case but explains the errors above.

Comment: @MattG: You can always replace `common_type_t<Args...>` by `common_type_t<decay_t<Args>...>`, though, so it shouldn't be super annoying.

Comment: That would solve the error, but then I'd be forcing a return-by-value for my function. Ideally if all the Args return a const Foo&, I'd like the common type to be "const Foo &" too (in my use case).

Comment: @MattG: Yeah. You can add the reference back on later (conditionally on all the input types having been references).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, `common_type_t<T1, T2>` is (roughly) `std::decay_t<decltype(true? std::declval<T1>() : std::declval<T2>())>`. It decays the type - strip away referenceness, remove top-level cv-qualification, and does the array-to-pointer and function-to-pointer conversion.

So, `common_type<const type_info&, const type_info&>::type` is `type_info`. While `func1`'s declaration appears to work, you'll have serious problems writing its definition.

`common_type_t<T1, T2, T3>` is `common_type_t<common_type_t<T1, T2>, T3>`, so `common_type<const type_info&, const type_info&, const type_info&>::type` is `common_type<type_info, const type_info&>::type`.

That results in a mixed-value-category ternary expression, which by the rules in [expr.cond] will try to make a temporary `type_info` out of the chosen operand - which doesn't work because `type_info`'s copy constructor is deleted.

In SFINAE-friendly implementations, that results in `common_type<const type_info&, const type_info&, const type_info&>` having no member `type`. If you use a non-SFINAE-friendly implementation, you'll get a hard error instead.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely answers the question. Any ideas why this changed for C++14 though? Seems I'm missing something if my code worked before but not now :)

Comment: @MattG ^that (in a nutshell, so that `common_type_t<int, int>` isn't `int&&`).